# Does an Oathbreaker Paladin keep or lose their Paladin powers?

Tags: dnd-5e, paladin

I would like to know what happens with the powers of paladin — Divine Sense, Lay on Hands, Divine Smite and Divine Health — when a paladin becomes an Oathbreaker.

Comment: I edited the title to make it more informative in the list of questions on the front page, but I had to slightly guess at what exactly your point of concern is. Can you look at the edit and make sure this is still asking what you are meaning to ask? Thanks!

Comment: [What happens when a Paladin falls from grace?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62023)

Comment: This doesn't look like a duplicate to me. One of the things that can happen to a paladin who falls from grace is becoming an Oathbreaker paladin, but whether an Oathbreaker paladin retains their paladin class features is a separate question.

Comment: @ObliviousSage The real question in the duplicate is "Does the Paladin lose all of his/her powers, or does the loss from grace only mean they are abandoned by their deity or order?" and the accepted (and only) answer there also answers this question.

Comment: @ObliviousSage (@LegendaryDude) My hueristic on dupe-voting is to look at whether the *answers* to the other question clearly and obviously answer this question, not so much whether the *questions* are facially duplicates. But maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 6):

RAW, they get to keep all of those powers.

As described on pg. 97 of the DMG:

> The paladin replaces the features specific to his or her Sacred Oath with the Oathbreaker features.

Since abilities like Divine Smite and Lay on Hands are class features that are not specific to the Sacred Oath, the paladin will get to keep them.